# Connecting to a database server in Android

Tags: java, android

I have an Android application with a user authentication module. Currently the system checks the user name locally. I need it to connect to a remote database server and check the user names by looking at the remote server. What is the most efficient way to do such task on Android?

Comment: One way is to communicate via sockets and send a object, deserialize it and access the database on the server side.

Comment: The most efficient way to use web services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use Mysql server . We need to use the website in between the android app and database.
The android makes the call to website and the website request to mysql database .In return the mysql database provides the data to the website which further returns the json format to the application. finally the data from the web is parsed and used in our application.

For more detail about Mysql with php [click here](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/)

Comment: Is there any other way to do this without an HTTP client?

Comment: The efficient way to perform remote database access is web page . The json can be used for data exchange.for more info [link] (http://webdesignergeeks.com/mobile/android/android-login-authentication-with-remote-db/)